# Can an Appendix to an insurance policy be patented as a novel invention?

Tags: pct, business-methods

Can an Appendix to an insurance policy be patented as a novel invention?  I have filed a PCT application that came back with the search report indicating that every claim considered Novel, Inventive STep, and Industrial Application all marked YES, however, I do not include a machine in this method, so I am concerned that although the invention overcomes a problem for mid-level to larger businesses in by improving the overall insurability of a project, some rules may consider it an abstract idea?  Any ideas to overcome the machine test for a business method patent?

Comment: I'll wait for an actual lawyer to answer (my guess would be no) but it would be good to specify the country you are considering patenting in.

Comment: The US and Europe.  Also, the invention is actually a structure if that matters

Comment: Has the patent application  or the invention been published? If yes, it's to late now to do anything proactively which could not be done after an actual office action.

Comment: It has been published but there have not been any office actions yet

Comment: Why don't you just link the publication? The answer to your title question (without knowing more) is 100% NO. Data structures are also not patentable as being ineligible subject matter under Section 101.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of Copyrights?